# Posture recognition without ML python

Tags: python-2.7, accelerometer, gyroscope

Is it possible to recognise different postures (sitting, lying, walking, standing etc) using just the accelerometer and gyro(3 axis) data in python? I am not familiar with machine learning technique implementations ( just know that we can use the classifiers for such cases) and just curious whether it is possible with moderate accuracy without ML? Any link or idea with basic implementation code will be helpful. Just not getting any good idea from Google or anywhere else. Please help.

Comment: Try OpenCV in python, you will get it

Comment: OpenCV is image recognition based solution, presently I am working with sensors. Tensorflow can help but again I am on python 2.7 plus all the solutions are machine learning based.